# How do I delete apache from OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, install, apache

How do I delete apache from OS X Yosemite? I want to start with a new unaltered configuration so I will also need to know how to install the latest version.
Following other posts to delete/reinstall apache I already tried the "apt-get" and "get" commands but they couldn't been found.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need to delete apache as you should not touch any executable under /usr/bin as Apple controls updating of this (i.e. could install it again). apt-get etc are not OS X or Unix commands but one packaging system for Linux.

Any install of apache will put it in a different place to where Apple puts it.

To install Apache if you want to use a packaging system look at Macports, Homebrew or Fink. (if deb is the packaging you know then look at Fink)

Otherwise the easiest installs are using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/), or use Apple's configuration in OS X Server

What you use depends on your knowledge and what you want to use it for and to use the correct tutorials i.e. not that that assume Linux

Comment: I second the use of MAMP and just stay away from the Apache that is built into Mac OS. The built-in Apache is welded very tightly to the OS and if you mess it up, restoring it can be less than fun. With MAMP you just back up what you need, delete the folder and start again, easy-peasy!

Answer (score 0):

apache2 is a "build-in" module of OS X. It's a bad idea to delete it.
You may find the original configuration file in `/etc/apache2/original` folder.

btw, apt-get is the package management of linux base on dpkg. For OS X, the package management is [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org)

Comment: Or package management using  Fink which does use apt-get